# What is the walk of this graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image]

1. A walk that is not a trail from vertex 1 to vertex 3;
2. A trail that is not a path from vertex 1 to vertex 3;
3. A path from vertex 1 to vertex 3.

How can I describe these walks?

Comment: Just list vertices in the order in which they’re encountered. Do you know what distinguishes a trail or a path from other walks?

Comment: V(H) = {0,1,2,3,5,6}  v1e2v2e3v3 is that a walk without a trail?

Comment: There is no reason to mention edges, which in this graph are unlabelled anyway. I assume that you mean the walk $123$; it’s both a path, since no vertices are repeated, and a trail, since no edges are repeated.

Comment: So, **1652123** is a walk and it's not a trail because it has repeated edges ? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Yes, that’s right. It’s also not a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Using the definitions of a walk, path and trial, we can figure out what exactly it is that you must find

1. A trail is a walk where no edges are repeated. So we must thus find a walk between vertices 1 and 3 in which edges ARE repeated.
2. A path is a walk in which no vertices are repeated. We must thus find a trail (a walk in which no edges are repeated), but in which at least one vertex is repeated.
3. Find a walk between vertex 1 and 3 in which no vertices are repeated.

I will leave it to you to find appropriate examples from your graph that matches the given descriptions above respectively.

Comment: Could you give me an example ?